# How to find the min and max AND corresponding x-value from a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to be able to find the min and max of a pandas data frame AND the corresponding X-value. As of now, I just have it find the Y-Value max and min, but I can't figure out how to provide a corresponding X-Value. What can I do to get this corresponding value?

So this finding of the min and max is included in a loop for writing an excel file and I want to eventually write out them max or min values in the excel file as well. I have tried doing this function to give the corresponding values

maxVal = dfspectra.loc[dfspectra['Current (mA)'].idxmax()]
minVal = dfspectra.loc[dfspectra['Current (mA)'].idxmin()]

This did not work and only gives me NaN or says that the data frame cannot be callable

Here is the initial introduction of the data frame:

```
for filename in filestoprocess:
    baseName=os.path.basename(os.path.basename(filename))
    dfspectra=pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows = 1, delimiter =        "\s+|\t+|\0+", header = None, names = ['Potential (V)','Current (mA)'],     engine='python', skipfooter=1,skipinitialspace=True)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(dfspectra['Potential (V)'],dfspectra['Current (mA)'],     "ok")
    ax.set(xlabel='Potential (V)', ylabel='Current (mA)', title='CV Data')
```

And here is my attempt of finding the max/min and corresponding x-value:

```
 ymax = np.max(dfspectra['Current (mA)'])
 ymin = np.min(dfspectra['Current (mA)'])
 maxVal = dfspectra.loc[dfspectra['Current (mA)'].idxmax()]
 minVal = dfspectra.loc[dfspectra['Current (mA)'].idxmin()]
```

When I put min or maxVal into the console, it gives my full data frame and when I try maxVal(dfspectra['Current (mA)'], it says that the data frame is not callable. I thought that the numpy function finds the Y-value while the loc function gives the X-value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
indx_max = np.argmax(dfspectra['Current (mA)'])
x_max = dfspectra.iloc[indx_max]
```

The first statement finds the index that contains the maximum value in column `Current (mA)` in your `dfspectra`. The second statement returns the row corresponding to the index from first row. For minima, use `np.argmin`.

```
indx_min = np.argmin(dfspectra['Current (mA)'])
x_min = dfspectra.iloc[indx_min]
```

Comment: So I followed this exactly and its giving me a type error: Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key

Comment: Can you provide the output of `indx_max = np.argmax(dfspectra['Current (mA)'])`? Can you also try `x_max = dfspectra.iloc[indx_max, :]`?

Comment: I actually figured it out by turning my values into a numpy array and then using argmax. Thanks for the help!